# Retrieve value from linked list struct give wrong value

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a function that create a linked list of struct.

```
struct words {
    char * word;
    words next;
};
typedef struct words s_words;
typedef words * Words;
```

I got a function that create my linked list using this code

```
Words w = NULL; // start of the list
Words t; // temp node

if (t = (Words) malloc(sizeof(s_words))) {

    t->word = a_string_created;
    t->next = w;
    w = t; // Adding at start of the list
}
```

If I made a `printf("%s",t->word)` and `printf("%s",a_string_created)` I got the same value.

My problem is when  I try to retrieve `word` from an another function.

```
int readWords(Words list, char * wordRead) {

    if (list != NULL) {
        //strcpy(wordRead,list->word);
        wordRead = list->word;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

I can't get the value in `readWords`. A `printf("%s",list->word)` in it give me a strange caracter. And from the caller function

```
char rw[11]; //I've try char* rw too
readWords(aList,rw);
```

`printf("%s",rw)` print nothing.

I'm stuck with this for hours now. For sure there's something I don't see/understand.

**Edit:**

I solved partly my problem by replacing `t->word = a_string_created;` by `strcpy(t->word, a_string_created);` Now on my printfs, I print string value. But the value have slightly change for some values ex.: test become uest !!

**Answer**

Change `t->word = a_string_created;` to `t->word = strdup(a_string_created);`

Anyone can help and explain to me where and why I'm wrong ?

Comment: BTW: why don't you use the function's _return value_ to **return the value**, instead of the silly 1 or 0 ?

Comment: It's a school homework and I can't change the signature for readWords.

Comment: maybe discuss it with your teacher then. It looks clearly wrong to me. Returning NULL seems to be a good indication of _not found_ )

Answer (score 2):

The problem happens because your `readWords` misuses the buffer: rather than copying the string from the list into it, `readWords` assigns it as a pointer. Since `rw` is passed by value, the content of the buffer remains uninitialized, leading to invalid printouts due to undefined behavior.

There are several ways of fixing this problem:

- Use `strcpy` to copy the content of `list->words` into the `wordRead` buffer, or
- Change `readWords` to take a pointer to a pointer for `wordRead`, and assign it `list->words`.

The `strcpy` approach is less safe, unless you take the size of the buffer as well. The pointer to pointer approach looks like this:

```
int readWords(Words list, char **wordRead) {
    if (list != NULL) {
        *wordRead = list->word;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The call looks like this:

```
char *rw;
if (readWords(aList, &rw)) {
    printf("%s", rw)
}
```

Comment: It's a school homework and I can't change the signature for readWords. But I can change everything from the "caller function".

Comment: @PatrickPellegrino Use `strcpy` then - you have started along the right track, but then you commented out the right call. If you use `strcpy`, the assignment would have to go.

Comment: I have to comment it because I receive a segmentation fault thinking that was my problem. Maybe my problem is in my List while printf("%s",list->word) in readWords give me bad output.

Comment: @PatrickPellegrino You may get a segfault when the word is longer than 10 characters (11 characters when counting the null terminator). Another possibility is that the list element may have been `free`d, or the pointer inside the list element points to an invalid memory location.

Comment: Solved partly the problem. Replacing t->word = a_string_created; by strcpy(t->word,a_string_created); now give "string" for my printfs BUT the value of those string have slightly changed (the first value of the string it's the next caracter in ASCII) !!!!

Comment: @PatrickPellegrino That's because you did not allocate space to `t->word` before copying. The pointer points to a random place in memory, causing random overwrites. What you need is either calling `strdup` (i.e. `t->word = strdup(a_string_created);` or changing declaration of `word` from `char *word` to `char word[11]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're allocating memory for your `struct` but failing to allocate memory for your string.

Not only that but your function attempts to set the `char *` variable `wordRead` to the beginning of the stored string. But it never returns this value outside the function - which appears to be the intent of the function. Your second function should read:

```
int readWords(Words list, char **wordRead) {
    if (list != NULL) {
        *wordRead = list->word;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

Comment: It's a school homework and I can't change the signature for readWords. But I can change everything from the "caller function".

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you need to pass a double pointer for wordRead. The way you did it, you just modify a local value.

So the correct prototype is `int readWords(Words list, char ** wordRead)`.

Comment: It's a school homework and I can't change the signature for readWords. But I can change everything from the "caller function".

Comment: @PatrickPellegrino In that case you have to provide memory by the caller and copy the value to the buffer passed to readWords. - Btw: If the caller passes such a buffer, it's good practice to pass the buffer's size along with the pointer to avoid Overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `struct` you need to allocate for `char*`. if there is no space allocated for your char data, your pointer is already pointing to garbage.

Secondly `strcpy` is not always safe unless you explicitly check the size of data you are trying to copy and make sure you string HAS a `'\0'` in the end. `strncpy` is safer than `strcpy`.

Comment: BTW: `strncpy() is **not** safer than `strcpy()`. It only has _different_ problems. (such as not null-terminating the result string(